# Returning back to the beginning of a block of code?

Tags: c#, return

I need to return back to the beginning of the code shown here after a user enters the wrong key.  Is there any simple line of code that will just return back to another line?  As you can see I already have an if statement set up so I can just add something that can return back to the beginning or to another area in my code.  I am really quite new to c# and programming in general.  I really just don't want to have to enter all the code again into another if statement that would produce the same issue.  I would preferably like to have the code just run again after a user enters a wrong key, because then they can re-read it without having to start from scratch again.

```
//Runs battle interactive
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("You have encountered a simple guard!  He deals 2 damage per attack and has 1 HP.");
Console.WriteLine("You currently have: " + Program.Inventory);
Console.WriteLine("Choose a weapon!");
var input2 = Console.ReadKey();


//Key checker for items
switch (input2.Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.D1:
        Console.WriteLine("");
        if (Items.iniFists == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have attacked with your Fists for 1 DMG!");
        }
        else
        {
            //this will never run, just a placeholder
            Console.WriteLine("You Don't have your fists!");
            switch (input2.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    if (Items.iniFists == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have attacked with your Fists for 1 DMG!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //this will never run, just a placeholder
                        Console.WriteLine("You Don't have your fists!");
                    }
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D2:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    if (Items.iniLongsword == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to attack with the Longsword for 2 DMG!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You don't have a longsword!");
                    }
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D3:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    if (Items.iniBow == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to attack with the Bow for 3 DMG!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You don't have a Bow!");
                    }
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D4:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    if (Items.iniLightstaff == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to attack with the Lightstaff for 4 DMG!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You don't have a Lightstaff!");
                    }
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D5:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("You can't attack with an Apple!");
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D6:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("You can't attack with a Golden Key!");
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D7:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("You can't attack with a Steak!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.D2:
        Console.WriteLine("");
        if (Items.iniLongsword == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to attack with the Longsword for 2 DMG!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You don't have a longsword!");
        }
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.D3:
        Console.WriteLine("");
        if (Items.iniBow == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to attack with the Bow for 3 DMG!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You don't have a Bow!");
        }
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.D4:
        Console.WriteLine("");
        if (Items.iniLightstaff == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to attack with the Lightstaff for 4 DMG!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You don't have a Lightstaff!");
        }
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.D5:
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("You can't attack with an Apple!");
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.D6:
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("You can't attack with a Golden Key!");
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.D7:
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("You can't attack with a Steak!");
        break;
}
```

Comment: When the user pressed the wrong key, wouldn't it be better if you just ask to enter that specific key again?

Comment: Can't you set your code in a function and call it again and again until the user press the correct key ? That's pretty much why functions exist

Comment: Don't show us THAT code (wrap it into a function, both in the example and in your real code), show us how you (would) use it.

Comment: Kindly minimize the code, and just show the relevant part of code. Its too complicated to understand the whole code for just one line problem.

Comment: Complicated? How is it complicated? More than needed yes, complicated... no.

Comment: I would post the answer but this question is on-hold, ugh. It's a valid question - just could of been asked better.

Comment: I think that is a bit better.

Answer (score 3):

C# supports labels in code, however it is not recommended due to the fact that it violates many coding best practices, but I guess there is always an exception to any rule.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Start:
        Console.WriteLine("Start Here... Press any key");
        var key = Console.ReadKey(true);

        switch (key.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.A:
                goto MyLabel;

            case ConsoleKey.B:
                goto MyLabel2;

            case ConsoleKey.C:
                goto MyLabel3;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Bad Choice");
                goto Start;

        }

    MyLabel:
        Console.WriteLine("MyLabel: A");
        goto Start;

    MyLabel2:
        Console.WriteLine("MyLabel: B");
        goto Start;


    MyLabel3:
        Console.WriteLine("MyLabel: C");
        goto Start;
    }
}
```

You can find more information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d96yfwee.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you have a couple options, you can use a while loop

```
bool continue = true;
while(continue == true)// or you can simply type "while(continue)"
{
    /* everything inside the `while` loop will be 
       repeated until `continue` is not `true`. */
}
```

you can also use methods

```
public static void doStuff()
{
    // insert stuff here
}
```

and then you can call that from elsewhere in your class

```
if(x = 6)
{
    doStuff();  //this line does the stuff
    doStuff();  // this line does the stuff again.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One answer to this is to check that you have valid input in a loop like this:

```
while (true)
{
    ConsoleKey i = Console.ReadKey()
    if (i == ConsoleKey.D1 || ... ) //Check if it's equal to any valid key, you 
                                    //might be able to simplify it with <= and 
                                    //>= if valid keys are sequential.
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid key");
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a goto statement at the end of your switch block:

```
SwitchStatement: switch(input2.Key)
...
default:
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid key pressed");

    goto SwitchStatement;
    break;
```

}